# Ruby Check all conditions for two values

Tags: ruby

I’m usually working in Swift language but I’m wondering how can this be achieved in Ruby

Thanks

```
if url == nil && image == nil {
}
else if url != nil && image == nil {
}
else if url == nil && image != nil {
} 
else if url != nil && image != nil {
}
```

Comment: With if and else statements, of course. I don't understand what sort of answer you're looking for here.

Comment: Do you have a implementation for some reason when I have a image but not a url it’s not working correctly

Comment: What exactly does your non-working code look like then, because the code you posted right now is not valid Ruby?

Comment: if image != nil && url != nil 
     dict = {:image => image , :url => url} 

   elsif url != nil && image == nil 
   dict = {:image => image, :url => "testURL"} 

   elsif image != nil && url == nil 
   dict = {:image => true , :url => ft.url} 
  
 end

Comment: It sounds like you're new to Ruby. Welcome! http://learnxinyminutes.com/docs/ruby/ might become a very valuable resource to you and your journey.

Answer (score 3):

```
case [url.nil?, image.nil?]
when [false, false]
  # ...
when [false, true]
  # ...
when [true, false]
  # ...
else
  # ...
end
```

Comment: this is very slick.

Comment: Note that the brackets are crucial – `when [true, false]` and `when true, false` are **not** equivalent in this case.

Answer (score 0):

```
if url.nil? && image.nil?
  puts 'a'
elsif image.nil?
  puts 'b'
elsif url.nil?
  puts 'c'
else
  puts 'd'
end
```